Python / Pyinstaller convert: TypeError: join() argument must be str,bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'list'
Full disclosure since I'm being voted down: I am not a  programmer, have no training, and this is my first Python script. I have no idea how to research this issue other than Google searches and they have not been helpful for this issue.
I have done a lot of research to write this code so far. I think I have one final issue to overcome to be able to convert the script to an exe file. I think I have found the problem (with some help from the comments so far). But, I can't figure out how to fix it. Any assistance would be appreciated.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MyDesktop\Trading executions Conversions\Convert_TopStepX_Orders_to_Pinescript.py", line 126, in <module>
    modify_spreadsheet(os.path.join(script_dir, xlsx_file), output_file)
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen ntpath>", line 139, in join
  File "<frozen genericpath>", line 188, in _check_arg_types
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'list'

The modify spreadsheet line of code referred to above has a note above it "# Call the function"
The intention is to modify all of the xlsx files, then modify all the names of the xlsx files. For this, I think, the code is making a list of files to alter, then cycling through that list.
But, the code isn't looking for a list the second time - it is looking for a file. So, I'll be researching this to try to find a solution. But, if anyone here can help that would be great.
Thanks so far to John Gordon for getting me this far!
Here is the section of the script that is causing issues:
# Get the script directory
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
output_folder = os.path.join(script_dir, "Trade Executions Scripts")
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

def modify_spreadsheet(input_file, output_file):
    # Read the Excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(input_file)

    # Remove rows with "cancelled by system" or "cancelled by trader" in any cell
    df = df[~df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('cancelled by system|cancelled by trader|Maximum position exceeded', case=False).any(), axis=1)]

    # Convert the date and time column to the desired format
    df.iloc[:, 9] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 9]).apply(lambda x: f"{x.year}, {x.month}, {x.day}, {x.hour}, {x.minute}, {x.second}")

    # Save the updated spreadsheet without header\title row
    df.to_excel(output_file, index=False, header=False)

# Get the list of all xlsx files in the input directory
xlsx_file = [file for file in os.listdir(output_folder) if file.endswith(".xlsx")]
xlsx_files = [f for f in os.listdir(script_dir) if f.endswith(".xlsx")]

# Loop over the xlsx files and modify them
for xlsx_file in xlsx_files:
    input_file = os.path.join(script_dir, xlsx_file)
    output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{os.path.splitext(xlsx_file)[0]}_modified.xlsx")

# Call the function
modify_spreadsheet(os.path.join(script_dir, xlsx_file), output_file)
print(f"Modified {xlsx_file} and saved to {output_file}")

I modified it as follows to isolate some errors pointed out to me by John Gordon (thank you, sir!).
But, my issue still remains. The modifications have now caused the issue to occur when running the script in Python (which is a bonus as I don't have to convert it to an exe to reproduce the error).

Please include a minimal reproducible example.  Also your two sets of code don't include the part where modify_spreadsheet(os.path.join(script_dir, xlsx_file_), output_file).  What is script_dir?  Either script_dir is a list or xlsx_file is a list.

Thank you very much to checking out my script! I posted the whole script at the bottom.  I have a lot of imports at the top as I've been trying to figure out why this isn't working once it is converted into an .exe file!

@shaneaus: The line that throws the error (modify_spreadsheet(os.path.join(script_dir, xlsx_file_), output_file)) is not included in the code you posted.

I removed the two snippets to prevent confusion and just have the entire code posted.
I, also, noted that the line in the error message is preceded by a note as follows:
Call the function
modify_spreadsheet(os.path.join(script_dir, xlsx_file), output_file)

This really doesn't look like a [mre]. A good MRE contains only the code you need to reproduce the problem and no more.

This code is the problem:
xlsx_file = [file for file in os.listdir(output_folder) if file.endswith(".xlsx")]
xlsx_files = [f for f in os.listdir(script_dir) if f.endswith(".xlsx")]

# Loop over the xlsx files and modify them
for xlsx_file in xlsx_files:
    input_file = os.path.join(script_dir, xlsx_file)
    output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{os.path.splitext(xlsx_file)[0]}_modified.xlsx")
    modify_spreadsheet(input_file, output_file)
    print(f"Modified {xlsx_file} and saved to {output_file}")

# Call the function
modify_spreadsheet(os.path.join(script_dir, xlsx_file), output_file)

The call to os.path.join() at the bottom (inside the call to modify_spreadsheet) is passing xlsx_file as its second argument.  But xlsx_file is a list, as you see at the top of this code.  You can't pass a list to os.path.join(), hence the error.

Ok. I understand what you're saying. But, I still can't figure out how to fix it.  If I can't pass a list to "os.path.join()" then how do I fix it? It works great when I run the python script. So, I don't know how to make it work once it is translated into an .exe.

The purpose of os.path.join() is to join together two components of a filepath, typically a directory name and a file name.  So in this code, it seems like you were expecting xlsx_file to be a single filename.  But it's a list instead.  So, "how do I fix it" depends on what you intended, which I cannot guess.

Also, I will point out that this code might have a subtle bug.  You create xlsx_file as a list, but then you also have the loop for xlsx_file in xlsx_files:.  If this loop executes at least once, then xlsx_file is reassigned to be the current item from the loop.  But if xlsx_files is empty, then that loop never executes at all, and xlsx_file retains its original value of a list.  So, on the last line of that code, xlsx_file may be a list or it may be a string.

So, what I want the code to do is look in the folder for one or multiple xlsx files, and modify any/all of them.
So, I guess it is creating a list of xlsx files to look at - but, when the code attempts to modify each file in the list, it is expecting a file and seeing the list instead of looping through each file in the list.
Problem is I don't know enough about Python code to ask the correct questions to AI to solve this problem. AI gives me a variations on the above.  And, it works in Python. It just won't work when converted to an .exe.
Hence my inability to figure it out.

@shaneaus You're already calling modify_spreadsheet() inside the for xlsx_file in xlsx_files: loop, so it seems like that will process all the files as you want.  So then what is the purpose of that last call to modify_spreadsheet  at the bottom of the code, after the loop has finished?

What this code is intended to do:
convert any .csv files in the folder to xlsx. / create a folder to store the soon to be new files /
modify any xlsx file in the folder /
rename the files /
split the files according to the number of rows into multiple files with no more than 25 rows each (with overlap as needed) /
for each file - use the data in each row, add text to the data and create a text file using the data and text. / end

Ok. I did some research and modified the code just a bit. It removed the double entry for the "modify_spreadsheet" lines. But, still didn't fix the issue above. I notice that I'm being voted down. I guess due to my initial post not showing enough effort?  I'm struggling because I am not a "coder," have never been trained, this is my first Python script, and I really don't even know how to research this other than Google searches which have not been helpful. So, I REALLY appreciate you help!

@shaneaus I think this question is being downvoted because it has become "I have this big program and something is wrong with it and I don't know how to fix it, please help me", which isn't the purpose of this website.

Ok. I was unaware of that. On the home page it states find answers to your technical questions.  Do you have a suggestion for a website where I could go to request assistance? I don't want to be bothering people on this site if that is not it's purpose. But, I need to figure this one specific issue out and I've done plenty of searching and nothing is coming up. I have overcome a LOT of issues with this code on my own. But, this one has me stumped. If you decide not to respond I understand.

I researched your previous comments and adjusted the main body of my code above. I now get an error running the script - I'll take that as a win as I don't have to convert it to an exe file to get the error!

Ok. I finally figured out how to fix this issue. I had to rewrite the code as follows:
# Iterate through all .xlsx files in the current directory
for file in os.listdir(script_dir):
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        # Load the spreadsheet
        df = pd.read_excel(file)

        # Remove rows with "cancelled by system" or "cancelled by trader" in any cell
        df = df[~df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('cancelled by system|cancelled by trader|Maximum position exceeded', case=False).any(), axis=1)]

        # Remove unwanted columns: A, B, C, D, K, Q
        df = df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 16]], axis=1)

        # Save the updated spreadsheet without header\title row
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, file)
        df.to_excel(output_file_path, index=False, header=False)
        print("Reformated data in xlsx files")

